# Don't Input more than 20 comma separated or new-line separated serial no and alpha-numeric in textarea in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex, textarea

Here is my problem statement. Any help will be great.

Users are allowed to input text in the textarea with below restrictions.

- Only AlphaNumeric entries(Serial nos) are allowed.
- Only 20 Entries (It can be comma separated like FVO01,FVO02,FVO03 ..)
  or new line like
  FVO01.
  FVO02.
  FVO03 etc.
- User can copy and paste from notepad or excel sheet so in doing so there might be more than 1 new line between 2 serial numbers, so have to take care of that also.

My Approach:
Trim all the spaces first.
Replace all new line(/n) characters with comma(,). If it's already comma-separated entry then conversion won't affect anything.
Count length and alert if it is more than 20.

Here is what I have tried till now, somehow capture and replace new line isn't working.

Looking for a better solution satisfying all of above conditions. Thanks

```
function checkValidations(newValue) {
                    $ctrl.serialNos = newValue;
                    
                    var comma = "";                     
                    if($ctrl.serialNos) {
                    comma = $ctrl.serialNos.replace(/\s/g, "");
                    comma = $ctrl.serialNos.replace(/\n/g, ",");
                    comma = comma.split(",");
                    
                    
                    var alphaNumeric = /^[(a-z)(A-Z)(0-9),]+$/;
                    if($ctrl.serialNos) {
                    if(!($ctrl.serialNos.match(alphaNumeric))) {
                        alert("Please enter only Alphanumeric values")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (comma.length > 21 ) {                           
                        alert("You can not enter More than 20 serial nos");
                    }
```

Comment: Please try `console.log(string2.split(/\n|,/g).length <= 20 && /[A-Za-z0-9]+/.test(string2.replace(/[\s\n,]+/g, "")));`

Comment: it's converting /n to comma now but I am counting serial no based on comma. so if there are multiple /n(let say 3) between 2 serial nos then it would be converted to 3 commas and although I have 2 serial nos, my total count of serial nos will be 5 which will affect my validation. It won't allow me to input after 17 serial nos.
any workaround for that

Comment: Okay you want to convert new lines to comma? Please check this [`\n+`](https://regex101.com/r/ynOdXR/1). Please do notice the commas are present there.

Comment: thanks, this helped in resolving my problem

Comment: I'm glad it helped=)Please consider upvoting the answer provided below. It'll help the answerer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\s` matches all whitespace, including new lines, so you will need to replace the new lines first.

```
comma = $ctrl.serialNos.replace(/\n+/g, ",");
comma = comma.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

Comment: it's converting /n to comma now but I am counting serial no based on comma. so if there are multiple /n(let say 3) between 2 serial nos then it would be converted to 3 commas and although I have 2 serial nos, my total count of serial nos will be 5 which will affect my validation. It won't allow me to input after 17 serial nos.
any workaround for that

Comment: @Saket No problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could match an alphanumeric entry, and repeat 0 - 19 times an alphanumeric entry which can be preceded by either 1 or more newlines or a comma

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(?:[\r\n]+|,)[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,19}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed (alphanumeric entry)
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:[\r\n]+|,)` Match either 1+ newlines or a single comma
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed characters
- `){0,19}` Close non capture group and repeat 0-19 times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RaM70L/1)

You could use [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to check for a valid input

```
if (!pattern.test(s)) {
    // ...
}
```